# How to handle an apostrophe in pipes.quote() python

Tags: python, linux, command

I am using `pipes.quote()` function to format my command/path
When there's an apostrophe in the command/path, this function is breaking one string into multiple strings.

For example, my command/string is

```
"cat 'test's dir/test's file.txt'"
```

And `pipes.quote()` is converting it into

```
'cat '"'"'test'"'"''"'"''"'"'s dir/test'"'"''"'"''"'"'s file.txt'"'"''
```

How do I frame string in a generic way so that it handles this condition and I can use the converted string/command to run on a linux machine?

Comment: `pipes.quote()` is deprecated. You should be using `shlex.quote()`

Comment: It looks like you already quoted the argument. This function should be used on an argument that hasn't been quoted, it will add the necessary quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `shlex.quote()`, not the obsolete `pipes.quote()`.

You need to give it a string that doesn't already have quotes around it. So

```
filename = "test's dir/test's file.txt"
command = f"cat {shlex.quote(filename)}"
os.system(command)
```

However, you can avoid the need for this entirely by using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system()`.

```
filename = "test's dir/test's file.txt"
subprocess.run(["cat", filename]);
```

This doesn't use the shell to execute the command, so there's no need for quoting.